# SQL Select order by index of value in an array

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, mysql-python, mysql-json

I have one array of strings    [“text1”, “text2”, “text3”] which happens to be saved as JSON array field on TableA

| uniqueID | strings |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["text1","text2","text3"] |

And a TableB with a column that will contain the value of one of those strings

| UNIQUEID | STRING | some other columns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | “text3” | value |
| 2 | “text1” | value |
| 3 | “text2” | value |
| 4 | “text1” | value |

I want to select from the table with results ordered by STRING_VALUE  but in the order in which they appear in the array

something like

```
    SET @v1 := (SELECT strings FROM tableA where uniqueID = 1);
    SELECT UNIQUEID from TABLEB
    Where 1=1
    Order by  array_index in @v1?
```

So that the result would be all the "text1" followed by "text2" etc
(not because of alpahbetical order but because that is the order in which they appear in the array in tableA)

| UNIQUEID |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 4 |
| 3 |
| 1 |

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

- join the two tables, by associating the json field to every row,
- use the [`JSON_SEARCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) function to extract the string index where the "*tableB.STRING*" is located
- transform the string index into an unsigned integer index using the `REPLACE` function followed by `CAST`
- use this index inside the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT tableB.UNIQUEID
FROM tableB
INNER JOIN tableA ON 1=1
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(
              JSON_SEARCH(tableA.strings, 'one', tableB.STRING),
              '"$[', ''), ']"', ''
         ) AS UNSIGNED),
         tableB.UNIQUEID
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6KkN9BU3yG6kPzi29m27nC/1).

Answer (score 1):

use `JSON_TABLE`.

```
SELECT b.UNIQUEID
FROM 
    tableB b
    JOIN 
        (
        SELECT * 
        FROM 
            JSON_TABLE
            (
                (SELECT STRS FROM tableA WHERE UNIQUEID = 1), '$[*]' 
                COLUMNS(
                SEQ FOR ordinality, 
                STR varchar(10) path '$')
            ) rs
        
        ) jt ON (b.STR = jt.STR)
ORDER BY jt.SEQ
;
```

###### table col definitionS.

tableA

| UNIQUEID | STRS |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |

tableB

| UNIQUEID | STR | OTHERS |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |

(tested on mariadb 10.6.5)